# How do I specify custom fonts to use when printing a page with weasyprint?

Tags: fonts, weasyprint

It seems that weasyprint doesn't support the @font-face css directive. Is there a different method for specifying fonts to use when producing pdfs with weasyprint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive is not supported.

weasyprint relies on using only currently installed fonts, as can be found through Pango/fontconfig.

This [short C program](http://www.lemoda.net/pango/list-fonts/index.html) will list all the fonts that can be accessed.

This command will test for a specific font name ([reference](http://librelist.com/browser//weasyprint/2013/8/13/how-do-i-use-custom-fonts-with-weasyprint/#cd884860f110bd734981dcfb2bcdfa43)):

```
pango-view -t 'Some test text' --font 'AwesomeFont'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run this on your linux box for all the MS fonts.  It was the solution to my problem!

`sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`